# Showing that $g$ is continuous by showing that a series converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity

> Define $g:\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{R}$ by
>   $$g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2x}{x^2-n^2}.$$Show
>   that $g$ is continuous.

$g$ can be rewritten as $$g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n+x}-\dfrac{1}{n-x}.$$Let $\epsilon>0$. Now, our job is to find a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $\left|x-y\right|<\delta$, $$\left|\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{y}+\sum\left(\dfrac{1}{n+x}-\dfrac{1}{n+y}+\dfrac{1}{n-y}-\dfrac{1}{n-x}\right)\right|<\epsilon.$$ That is; $$\left|\dfrac{y-x}{xy}+(y-x)\sum\left(\dfrac{1}{(n-y)(n-x)}-\dfrac{1}{(n+x)(n+y)}\right)\right|<\epsilon.$$ I believe I need to find the limit of that last sum, but I don't know how. Or at least I should find an upper bound $A$ so that I can find a $\delta$ such that $\delta<\dfrac{\epsilon}{AB}$ where $\dfrac{1}{xy}<B$. What should I do?

Comment: show that the series converges uniformly on compact subsets of it's domain of definition.

Comment: The series converges to $\pi\cot\pi x$.

Answer (score 1):

since you have removed the integers from the domain you only have to work within copies of the open unit interval. can you show that the convergence of the series (of *functions*) is uniform on closed subintervals (i.e. compact)?

Comment: In this course I'm taking we haven't covered uniform convergence yet.

Comment: @Fanni What course is that that poses you a problem like the one you posted but doesn't cover uniform convergence?